# Jupyter notebook custom.js not applied when using "Restarting & Run All"

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, customization

In order to get the name of a running Jupyter notebook, I first added the following line in ~/.jupyter/custom/custom.js

```
// Create a nb_name variable with the name of the notebook
IPython.notebook.kernel.execute('nb_name = "' + IPython.notebook.notebook_name + '"');
```

Then on my notebook when I run a cell with:

```
print(nb_name)
```

I get:

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-7e37f787d8df> in <module>()
----> 1 print(nb_name)

NameError: name 'nb_name' is not defined
```

To solve this issue I need to add a first line with an alert command:

```
alert("hello world from custom.js")

// Create a nb_name variable with the name of the notebook
IPython.notebook.kernel.execute('nb_name = "' + IPython.notebook.notebook_name + '"');
```

Then an alert window shows up when I load my notebook, and once I closed it, I get the notebook name as expected.

How could I make it work without any action from the user (I am using notebook version 5.0.0 and as I am not the admin of the server cannot update it)?

EDIT:

Question in [Waiting for kernel to be ready when executing code via Jupyter kernel (Jupyter Notebook extension)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52937659/waiting-for-kernel-to-be-ready-when-executing-code-via-jupyter-kernel-jupyter-n) solved partially the problem. Custom.js file containing:

```
Jupyter.notebook.events.one('kernel_ready.Kernel', () => {
     // Create a nb_name variable with the name of the notebook
     IPython.notebook.kernel.execute('nb_name = "' + IPython.notebook.notebook_name + '"');
});
```

Return the notebook name as expected. Now the problem is I still get the error message mentioned above when I "Restart & Run All". Any comment or idea would be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

*custom.js* `kernel_ready.Kernel` event is triggered only once when the page is loaded, but it is not triggered after `Restart & Run all` (or any variants of it). My solution to this problem is a bit hackie:

```js
/**
 * `kernel_ready` logic
 */
function custom_kernel_ready_handler() {
    IPython.notebook.kernel.execute('nb_name = "' + IPython.notebook.notebook_name + '"');
}

function handle_kernel_ready() {
    // Create a nb_name variable with the name of the notebook
     console.log('kernel_ready.Kernel: handle_kernel_ready() was triggered!');
     custom_kernel_ready_handler();

     Jupyter.notebook.events.one('kernel_ready.Kernel', () => {
         //this recursive behavior is esential for `restart` kernel
         handle_kernel_ready();
    });
}

Jupyter.notebook.events.one('kernel_ready.Kernel', () => {
     handle_kernel_ready();
});
```

Hoping for better solutions ...