# Waiting for kernel to be ready when executing code via Jupyter kernel (Jupyter Notebook extension)

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I'm building a Jupyter Notebook extension where I need to execute some code as soon as Kernel becomes ready during initialization. I'm executing my code as below, but I noticed that sometimes Kernel becomes ready before I load my extension, so the code inside my custom event never gets executed.

```
Jupyter.notebook.events.one('kernel_ready.Kernel', () => {
     // Couldn't execute this line, because kernel was already
     // ready when this event handler was attached
     Jupyter.notebook.kernel.execute(someCode)
});
```

Can I just trust notebook to execute the code without worrying about kernel to become ready? I'm guessing there is some type of queue, so the code would eventually get executed.

`Jupyter.notebook.kernel.execute(someCode)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The kernel may be fully ready before the nbextension subscribes to `kernel_ready` event. In that case we can directly use kernel:

```
if (Jupyter.notebook.kernel) {
    // ... 
} else {
  Jupyter.notebook.events.one('kernel_ready.Kernel', (e) => {
    // ...
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I am a total beginner in Javascript, but maybe I can provide some info, as your question partially solved and issue I posted a few days ago ([Jupyter notebook custom.js not applied when using "Restarting & Run All"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52917023/jupyter-notebook-custom-js-not-applied-when-using-restarting-run-all)).

Placing my code in

```
Jupyter.notebook.events.one('kernel_ready.Kernel', () => {
```

on the custom.js file allows me to guarantee it is executed when I load the script.